# Appending specified property of a specified header within a ini file

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I have a ini file containing **Headers** with respective **property** fields to it. For a given **Header2** and a **property2**  how do I append `AppendedValue` to the **property2** by either using `sed` or `awk`?

There may be **N** number of *Headers* and order of *Headers* need not be 1, 2 or 3.

Input File1 :

```
[Header1]

property1 = containsSomeValue
property2 = containsSomeValue
property3 = containsSomeValue

[Header2]

property1 = containsSomeValue
property2 = containsSomeValue
property3 = containsSomeValue


[Header3]

property1 = containsSomeValue
property2 = containsSomeValue
property3 = containsSomeValue
```

Output File1:

```
[Header1]

property1 = containsSomeValue
property2 = containsSomeValue
property3 = containsSomeValue

[Header2]

property1 = containsSomeValue
property2 = containsSomeValue AppendedValue
property3 = containsSomeValue


[Header3]

property1 = containsSomeValue
property2 = containsSomeValue
property3 = containsSomeValue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed`:

```
sed "/\[Header2\]/,/\[/{/^property2/ s/$/ AppendedValue/}" infile
```

This will look for the lines between `[Header2]` and `[` (which would be the start character of next unknown *Header*), then append the `AppendedValue` string to the end of a line if started with `property2`; the *`{sed-script}`* part only applies for the block matched within given patterns range, and other lines out of this range will be printed with no changes which is `sed`'s default action.

You can use above in this way too:

```
sed "/\[Header2\]/,/\[/{s/^property2.*/& AppendedValue/}" infile
```

If you want to be more specific:

```
sed "/^\[Header2\]/,/^property2/{/^property2/ s/$/ AppendedValue/}" infile
```